# MYSQL remove NOT IN subquery on table itself

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following query which displays a list of accounts with a certain margin level:

```
SELECT
    crm_margincall.id,
    crm_margincall.CreationTime,
    ba.name AS crm_bankaccount_id,
    crm_margincall.name,
    crm_margincall.MarginCallLevel,
    crm_margincall.UseOfEquityForMargin,
    crm_margincall.MarginRequired,
    crm_margincall.NetEquityForMargin,
    crm_margincall.MarginDeficit,
    crm_margincall.balance,
    crm_margincall.deposited,
    crm_margincall.prefunded,
    crm_margincall.required
FROM 
    crm_margincall
LEFT JOIN
    crm_bankaccount ba ON crm_margincall.crm_bankaccount_id = ba.id
WHERE 
    crm_margincall.name = 'MarginCall' 
AND 
    crm_margincall.MarginCallLevel >= 100
AND 
    crm_margincall.crm_account_id NOT IN 
    (
    SELECT 
        x.crm_account_id 
    FROM 
        crm_margincall x 
    WHERE 
        x.crm_account_id = crm_margincall.crm_account_id 
    AND 
        x.name = 'LevelDrop' 
    AND 
        x.MarginCallLevel < 100 
    AND 
        x.id > crm_margincall.id
    )
ORDER BY 
    id
DESC
```

This query, on a table of ~22.500 records takes >10 seconds to run, this is caused by the subquery defining the NOT IN section (tried NOT EXISTS, isnt much faster). How can I join this table on itself to achieve the same effect?

Comment: It would be much quicker/easier to answer if you provided the database schema, the results of `EXPLAIN`, or better yet, a working SQLFiddle ( http://www.sqlfiddle.com/ )

Comment: I can't provide data, sorry. Confidential.

Comment: No, not the data - I fully understand the need for confidentiality - just the schema, and only of those tables involved (not even all fields, at that). It is possible that you're missing an index, for example. *Totally* shooting in the dark, if you index like this `CREATE INDEX test_index ON crm_margincall(name, crm_account_id, MarginCallLevel, id)`, do the times change?

Comment: Ow wow, it does! Showing rows 0 - 42 (43 total, Query took 0.6868 seconds.) [id: 22685 - 22537]!

Comment: I'll post it as an answer then :-)

Comment: Accepted it as solution, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This query, on a table of ~22.500 records takes >10 seconds to run,
>   this is caused by the subquery defining the NOT IN section (tried NOT
>   EXISTS, isnt much faster). How can I join this table on itself to
>   achieve the same effect?

This can be done in several ways, but a scan of 22500 records taking 10" means either a hardware issue, or a very inefficient JOIN.

The most likely cause of the latter is a missing index or a misconfigured index, and to investigate this, you need to issue an EXPLAIN:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT ...
```

Totally shooting in the dark, judging from the selected columns being used, I'd try with

```
 CREATE INDEX test_index ON crm_margincall(name, crm_account_id, MarginCallLevel, id)
```

Other improvements might be possible, but you'd need to prepare a sample structure with some fake data in a SQLfiddle to really allow debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    SELECT
    crm_margincall.id,
    crm_margincall.CreationTime,
    ba.name AS crm_bankaccount_id,
    crm_margincall.name,
    crm_margincall.MarginCallLevel,
    crm_margincall.UseOfEquityForMargin,
    crm_margincall.MarginRequired,
    crm_margincall.NetEquityForMargin,
    crm_margincall.MarginDeficit,
    crm_margincall.balance,
    crm_margincall.deposited,
    crm_margincall.prefunded,
    crm_margincall.required
FROM 
    crm_margincall
LEFT JOIN
    crm_bankaccount ba ON crm_margincall.crm_bankaccount_id = ba.id
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        x.crm_account_id 
    FROM 
        crm_margincall x 
    WHERE 
        x.name = 'LevelDrop' 
    AND 
        x.MarginCallLevel < 100 
    AND 
        x.id > crm_margincall.id
    ) tt ON crm_margincall.crm_account_id = tt.crm_account_id 
WHERE 
    crm_margincall.name = 'MarginCall' 
AND 
    crm_margincall.MarginCallLevel >= 100

ORDER BY 
    id
DESC
```